# SQL query result in a textbox

Tags: php, sql

I am doing up a PHP page and I want to have SQL query result shown in a `textbox`. I tried searching for answers but I don't really understand any of it.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT MARK_TAB from disabled_tab where SCHOOL_CODE = 9999;
```

And I want the query to be shown here:

```
Mark <input type="text" style="width: 30px;" id="marktab" />
```

How do I do it? Appreciate it :)

Comment: You need to run the query on the database. Then you echo the data as the textbox value.

Comment: use value="<?php echo $result;?>"

Comment: How do you run the query?

Comment: There are _millions_ of examples for this on the internet. Really none fits your case?

Comment: I would suggest reading a bit about php markup and mysql functions. What you are trying to do is really simple. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this as an example:

```
<?php

// connect to mysql stuff
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_pass","database");

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MARK_TAB from disabled_tab where SCHOOL_CODE = 9999;");

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

?>

<!-- echo that results on the value attribute -->
<input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $result['MARK_TAB']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = SELECT MARK_TAB from disabled_tab where SCHOOL_CODE = 9999;
```

In your HTML

```
<input type="text" style="width: 30px;" id="marktab" value="<?php echo $result;?>" />
```

Comment: Where do I put this?
    $result = SELECT MARK_TAB from disabled_tab where SCHOOL_CODE = 9999;

Comment: In your PHP code, you need to assign the result of the sql query to a variable, then you can call that variable on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT MARK_TAB from disabled_tab where SCHOOL_CODE = 999"
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query)
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
{
  $yourvalue = $row['your_row'];
?>

<input type="text" style="width: 30px;" id="marktab" value="<?php echo $yourvalue?>"/>

<?php
}
?>php
```